# How to find intersection of 2 lists in least time complexity in python 3.5 excluding the built in set function?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, set-intersection

I know we can solve with this method but I am curious to know is there any other method with least time complexity.

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[2,3,5]
c=set(a).intersection(b)
```

This gives the answer but is there any shorter method?And it would also be helpful if someone explains what is the time complexity of this built in function in python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Shorter solution:

If you want a *shorter* method, you can use the `&` operator for *sets*, which is exactly an **intersection**:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [2, 3, 5]
>>> c = set(a) & set(b)
{2, 3}
```

## Time complexity:

Python has a module called [**timeit**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), which measures execution time of small code snippets. So in your case:

With the `intersection()` function:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; b = [2, 3, 5]; c = set(a).intersection(set(b))"

100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00989 usec per loop
```

With the `&` operator:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; b = [2, 3, 5]; c = set(a) & set(b)"

100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.01 usec per loop
```

You see that there is a very small difference between them (because in the inside they are the same thing). But there is no more efficient way of doing *set intersection*, because the built-in methods are enough optimized.

**[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)** is a table of time complexity of each collection method in Python. Look at the **set** section:

- Operation: **Intersection s&t**
- Average case: **O(min(len(s), len(t))**
- Worst case: **O(len(s) * len(t))**
- Notes: *replace "min" with "max" if t is not a set*